# Ruby multithreading Performance issues

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I am building Ruby application. I have a set of images that I want to greyscale. My code used to be like this:

```
def Tools.grayscale_all_frames(frames_dir,output_dir)
    number_of_frames = get_frames_count(frames_dir)
    img_processor = ImageProcessor.new(frames_dir)
    create_dir(output_dir)

    for i in 1..number_of_frames
        img_processor.load_image(frames_dir+"/frame_%04d.png"%+i)
        img_processor.greyscale_image
        img_processor.save_image_in_dir(output_dir,"frame_%04d"%+i)
    end
end
```

after threading the code:

```
def Tools.greyscale_all_frames_threaded(frames_dir,output_dir)
    number_of_frames = get_frames_count(frames_dir)
    img_processor = ImageProcessor.new(frames_dir)
    create_dir(output_dir)
    greyscale_frames_threads = []

    for frame_index in 1..3
        greyscale_frames_threads << Thread.new(frame_index) { |frame_number| 
            puts "Loading Image #{frame_number}"
            img_processor.load_image(frames_dir+"/frame_%04d.png"%+frame_number)
            img_processor.greyscale_image
            img_processor.save_image_in_dir(output_dir,"frame_%04d"%+frame_number)
            puts "Greyscaled Image #{frame_number}"
        }
    end

    puts "Starting Threads"
    greyscale_frames_threads.each { |thread| thread.join }

end
```

What I expected is a thread being spawned for each image. I have 1000 images. The resolution is 1920*1080. So how I see things is like this. I have an array of threads that I call .join on it. So join will take all the threads and start them, one after the other? Does that mean that it will wait until thread 1 is done and then start thread 2? What is the point of multithreading then?

What I want is this:

Run all the threads at the same time and not one after the other. So mathematically, it will finish all the 1000 frames in the same time it will take to finish 1 frame, right?

Also can somebody explain me what .join does?
From my understanding .join will stop the main thread until your thread(s) is or are done?
If you don't use .join, then the thread will run the background and the main thread will just continue.

So what is the point of using .join? I want my main thread to continue running and have the other threads in the background doing stuff?

Thanks for any help/clarification!!

Comment: maybe you should look into background worker tools like `resque`

Comment: "mathematically" -- If creating threads takes 0 amount of time and you have enough CPU cycles and RAM, then yes. In practice, this should hang up your PC badly.

Comment: *It will finish all the 1000 frames in the same time it will take to finish 1 frame, right?* Given 1000 cores and some gigs of RAM, yes.

Comment: @MarianTheisen I am not using rails.. And resque probably does the same thing as me

Comment: @TrtTrt not needed *There is no official requirement other than Ruby newer than 1.8.7.*

Comment: @Stefan, I know but I dont think resque is doing anything more than jus calling threads, like I am doing

Comment: 3,000 LOC just for calling `Thread#join`? :-)

Comment: I just don't want to use any external libraries. If somebody could answer my question that will be great

Comment: Said simply, I think you have some unsupportable expectations for your hardware. Look at throttling back your thread use to a reasonable level, maybe add RAM and CPUs to your machine and don't expect them to be done instantly. If you do something with code that takes its overall CPU load past 5% you are pushing it hard. I suspect you are totally burying your machine. Threads are not magical, they need hardware to feed on.

Comment: resque does a lot more that just creating threads, but it's your call ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So `join` will take all the threads and start them, one after the other?

No, the threads are started when invoking `Thread#new`. It creates a new thread and executed the given block within that thread.

> `join` will stop the main thread until your thread(s) is or are done?

Yes, it will suspend execution until the receiver (each of your threads) exists.

> So what is the point of using `join`?

Sometimes you want to start some tasks in parallel but you have to wait for each task to finish before you can continue.

> I want my main thread to continue running and have the other threads in the background doing stuff

Then don't call `join`.

After all it's not a good idea to start 1,000 threads in parallel. Your machine is only capable of running as many tasks in parallel as CPUs are available. So instead of starting 1,000 threads, place your jobs / tasks in a queue / pool and process them using some worker threads (number of CPUs = number of workers).

Answer (score 3):

This is only true if you have 1000 CPU cores and massive (read: hundreds and hundreds) of RAM.

The point of join is not to start the thread, but to wait until the thread has finished. So calling join on an array of threads is a common pattern for waiting for them all to finish.

Explaining all of this, and clarifying your misconception this requires digging a little deeper. At the C/Assembler level, mst modern OSes (Win, Mac, Linux, and some others) use a preemptive scheduler. If you have only one core, two programs running in paralel is a complete illusion. In reality, the kernel is switching between the two every few milliseconds, giving all of use slow processing humans the illusion of parallel processing.

In newer, more modern CPUs, there are often more than one core. The most powerful CPU's today can go up to (I think) 16 real cores + 16 hyperthreaded cores (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)). This means that you could actually run 32 tasks *completely in parallel*. But even this does not ensure that if you start 32 threads they will all finish at the same time.

Because of competition for resources that are shared between cores (some cache, all the RAM, harddrive, network card, etc.), and the essentially random nature of preemptive scheduling, the amount of time your thread takes can be estimated in a certain range, but not exactly.

Unfortunatly, all of this breaks down when you get to Ruby. Because of some hariy internal details about the threading model an compatibility, **only one thread can execute *ruby* code at a time**. So, if your image processing is done in C, happy joy joy. If it's written in Ruby, well, all the treads in the world arn't going to help you now.

To be able to actually run *Ruby* code in parallel, you have to use `fork`. `fork` is only available on Linux and Mac, and not Windows, but you can think of it as a fork in a road. One process goes in, two processes come out. Multiple processes can run on all your different cores at once.

So, take @Stefan's advice: use a queue and a number of worker threads = to # of CPU cores. And con't expect so much of your computer. Now you know why ;).

Comment: Well, "Only one thread can execute ruby code at a time" assuming you're using the default version of Ruby. An alternative Ruby implementation like JRuby or Rubinius will give you better threading characteristics with the downside of installing these things.

Comment: @RyanWilcox: true. And also at the disadvantage of losing any. Icompatable libraries. For all of its weaknesses, MRI is still the de facto standard.

Comment: So are you saying that if my CPU supports for example 2 threads, and I start 2 threads each time, it will run them in parallel, but if I run 3000 threads that will make the system run them in sequence?

Comment: @TrtTrt: Mostly. But you have to remember that you can't really depend on anything here. Preemptive scheduler's job is to get everything done, not just your process.