# Ruby thread limit - Also for any language

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am trying to process 1000 frames as fast as I can with Ruby. So I currently start 1000 threads (one for each frame). The result is bad. It uses a huge amount of memory and it is slow. My CPU is this http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/
It says that it supports 4 threads. (I am guessing 2 per CPU?).
So If I start 4 Ruby threads at a time, wait until they are done, and then start 4 more etc etc etc, it will take 250 'steps' to finish the processing right, instead of 1000?

EDIT: My code now:

```
beginning_time = Time.now
    limit=1
for frame_index in 1..limit
    greyscale_frames_threads << Thread.new(frame_index) { |frame_number| 
        puts "Loading Image #{frame_number}"
        img_processor.load_image(frames_dir+"/frame_%04d.png"%+frame_number)
        img_processor.greyscale_image
        img_processor.save_image_in_dir(output_dir,"frame_%04d"%+frame_number)
        puts "Greyscaled Image #{frame_number}"
    }
end

puts "Joining Threads"
greyscale_frames_threads.each { |thread| thread.join } #this blocks the main thread
end_time = Time.now
puts "Time elapsed #{(end_time - beginning_time)*1000} milliseconds"
```

Now for limit=1 this is what I get:

> Time elapsed 23504.805999999997 milliseconds

Now for limit=2 this is what I get:

> Time elapsed 53465.676 milliseconds

For limit=2 I was expecting 23504.805999999997 milliseconds.

This means that my code just fails. Threads have no meaning, here. Why? Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: How about writing a test utility which allows you to vary the number of threads. Then you can time the execution and work out the best.

Comment: I don't like testing and I don't really want to waste my time doing testing. It doesn't make sense testing Language A, against Language A. Theoretically this is not possible. Also I cant really test it, because if I run both tests at the same time, one will create 1000 threads, and the other one 4.. so I am just making things worse..

Comment: I'm not suggesting comparing language A to language B but rather a utility written in `ruby` which would allow you to inspect performance with different numbers of threads.

Comment: It still takes 1,000 "steps", but the work is done in parallel.

Comment: I have edited my question. Take a look please

Comment: @TrtTrt please read [Linuxios' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17172720/477037) to your other question again, Ruby threads are not going to help you here.

Comment: Ruby is pretty much failing in running things in parallel. What is the  point of having threads if you can't run them in parallel?

Comment: They do run in parallel but within one main thread. However, you can use [fork](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Process.html#method-c-fork) to launch your workers in a subprocess.

Comment: @TrtTrt: In Ruby, profiling (ie. testing for speed) is really really really quick and easy. You did right to ask at SO. Although I am not expert on profiling, people here will surely help you.

Comment: So what you telling me is that 'n' threads are running under 1 thread? What if I use 'fork' and spawn 4 threads as processes? Will that utilize the 'four' cores I have on my machine? Check Frederick Cheung's answer it, conflict with yours. And if they do run in parallel why did I get those time values?

Comment: @TrtTrt Yes, creating 4 subprocessses with fork will utilize your 4 cores. A process is not a thread.

Comment: @Trt Trt: Ruby MRI threading will not by itself fully utilise a multi-core CPU with running Ruby code. But whether that's a problem for you depends on what the threads are doing. If they are making long-running I/O calls to other processes on the same machine, you will see the benefit without needing separate processes. Threading and multi-processing as subjects can get quite complex doing even simple things. Most languages will make some compromises on what is easy and what is difficult out of the box.

Comment: @NeilSlater thanks for the clarification. Is the IO the reason that the time of execution doubles when I increase the limit in my code?

Comment: @Trt Trt: No, I don't think IO limits are affecting you from the numbers you are seeing. Your script speed is most likely restricted by available CPU, and you are correct in identifying that your machine has more available if only you could access it. Unfortunately Ruby threads alone don't give you access to more CPU cores. It depends a lot on what `img_processor` is doing, but my guess is it is doing something CPU intensive within the Ruby process.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this class, for example, to create a thread pool and schedule your work:

```
class Pool
  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
    @jobs = Queue.new
    @pool = Array.new(@size) do |i|
      Thread.new do
        Thread.current[:id] = i
        catch(:exit) do
          loop do
            job, args = @jobs.pop
            job.call(*args)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def schedule(*args, &block)
    @jobs << [block, args]
  end

  def shutdown
    @size.times do
      schedule { throw :exit }
    end
    @pool.map(&:join)
  end
end
```

You can then do `pool = Pool.new(32)` and after that schedule stuff like this:

```
pool.schedule do 
  # do your stuff
end
```

So that means (in this example) there will be a maximum of 32 threads, each popping some work that you scheduled.

Comment: Yes but this will not run them in parallel according to @Frederick's answer?

Comment: @Trt Trt: The threads will run as parallel as Ruby can manage. With Ruby MRI versions (including 1.9.3 and 2.0.0) that means they will timeshare one CPU core. It is worth noting that this is a normal state of affairs for threads in many systems - until a few years back, PC CPUs only had one core, and *all* threading was timesharing. True parallel threading by default on PCs is only a decade or so old (Intel Core Duo was released to big fanfare in 2006 for example). Ruby isn't alone in having limited support for it.

Comment: @TrtTrt if you want extended threading support, you might want to take a look at jruby, if that is at all possible for you. Then you basically have the full power of the jvm to your disposal.

Answer (score 3):

In the standard ruby interpreter only one thread ever runs at a time, so if you are compute bound adding threads don't help. If you search for GIL or GVL (global interpreter lock) you'll find lots written on this topic. If you are IO bound then threads waiting on IO will relinquish control so threads are still useful in this case.

C extensions can also relinquish the GVL and so have multiple threads running in parallel, however this is only possible on ruby 1.9.3+ and the C extension needs to have been written with this in mind.

If compute parallelism is important to you, you may want to look at jruby or rubinius, neither of which have a GVL. Of the two, jruby is more mature.

Lastly, creating 1 thread per task is wasteful - there's a certain amount of overhead involved, so the normal pattern is to have a pool of re-usable worker threads.

Comment: So kristofv's answer is wrong? In any way I can't run threads in parallel just with pure Ruby? So I don't get the point of having threads in Ruby if GVL exists

Comment: There's nothing wrong with kristofv's answer, it depends on the sort of work your threads do. If they mostly do stuff like IO, database queries or call into c extensions that opt out of the GVL then they will parallelise just fine. If they don't then on standard ruby you will only use one CPU core at a time

Comment: There are many different implementations of Ruby. Only very few of those have a GVL. Most implementations are perfectly capable of running threads in parallel.