# Ruby Concurrency I/O

Tags: ruby, multithreading, io

Following this, 
[Ruby thread limit - Also for any language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188065/ruby-thread-limit-also-for-any-language)

I am trying to understand why my threads are not working.
Some answer were pretty clear like:

"..creating 4 subprocessses with fork will utilize your 4 cores"
which this will be my final approach since threads don't seem to work in my case.

also this:

"..Ruby MRI threading **will not by itself fully utilise a multi-core CPU with running Ruby code**. But whether that's a problem for you depends on what the threads are doing. **If they are making long-running I/O calls to other processes on the same machine, you will see the benefit without needing separate processes**. Threading and multi-processing as subjects can get quite complex doing even simple things. Most languages will make some compromises on what is easy and what is difficult out of the box..."

Taking into consideration the second one, I have removed any processing from my code and just left I/O in it.

Here it is:

```
beginning_time = Time.now
img_processor.load_image(frames_dir+"/frame_0001.png")
img_processor.load_image(frames_dir+"/frame_0002.png")
end_time = Time.now
puts "Time elapsed #{(end_time - beginning_time)*1000} milliseconds"

beginning_time = Time.now
for frame_index in 1..2
    greyscale_frames_threads << Thread.new(frame_index) { |frame_number| 
        puts "Loading Image #{frame_number}"
        img_processor.load_image(frames_dir+"/frame_%04d.png"%+frame_number)
    }
end

puts "Joining Threads"
greyscale_frames_threads.each { |thread| thread.join } #this blocks the main thread
end_time = Time.now
puts "Time elapsed #{(end_time - beginning_time)*1000} milliseconds"
```

And what I am getting is this...

For the first non-threaded case:

> Time elapsed 15561.358 milliseconds

For the second threaded case:

> Time elapsed 15442.401 milliseconds

Ok, where is the performance increase? Am I missing something? 
Is the HDD blocking? 
Do I really need to spawn processes to see real parallelism in ruby?

Comment: Since you asked about I/O specifically, it is possible to do concurrent I/O without threads by using asynchronous I/O. Look at EventMachine as a way to do that.

Comment: And, perhaps, Celluloid::IO project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I really need to spawn processes to see real parallelism in ruby?

Yes, I think so:

```
require 'timeout'
require 'digest'
require 'benchmark'

def do_stuff
  Digest::SHA256.new.digest "a" * 100_000_000
end

N = 10
Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|

  x.report("sequential") do
    N.times do
      do_stuff
    end
  end

  x.report("subprocess") do
    N.times do
      fork { do_stuff }
    end
    Process.waitall
  end

  x.report("thread") do
    threads = []
    N.times do
      threads << Thread.new { do_stuff }
    end
    threads.each(&:join)
  end

end
```

Results for MRI 2.0.0:

```
                 user     system      total        real
sequential   3.200000   0.180000   3.380000 (  3.383322)
subprocess   0.000000   0.000000   6.600000 (  1.068517)
thread       3.290000   0.210000   3.500000 (  3.496207)
```

The first block (sequential) runs `do_stuff` 4 times, one after another, the second block (subprocess) runs on 4 cores, whereas the third block (thread) runs on 1 core.

---

If you change `do_stuff` to:

```
def do_stuff
  sleep(1)
end
```

The result is different:

```
                 user     system      total        real
sequential   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 ( 10.021893)
subprocess   0.000000   0.010000   0.080000 (  1.013693)
thread       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  1.003463)
```

Comment: I am guessing at this point we re talking about parallelism and not concurrency. In my mind I have related threads to concurrency and processes to parallelism. I am still confused about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188065/ruby-thread-limit-also-for-any-language, check kristofv's answer.  Frederick Cheung said, There's nothing wrong with kristofv's answer, it depends on the sort of work your threads do... So parallelism can't really be achieved with threads. You need to be careful what you tell them to do.?

Comment: Of course, you can achieve parallelism with threads. But there are some Ruby implementations which cannot run threads in parallel. Obviously, if you run your code on one of those, you won't see any performance gains.

Comment: Don't you need to wait for all the child processes to finish? You are calling multiple forks in your loop, so Process.waitall may be a better move.

Comment: Re: @JörgWMittag's comment: so is there any point to using threads in e.g. MRI which cannot run threads in parallel due to the Global Interpreter Lock? I was under the impression that there is still room for performance gain depending on what kind of program you have, i.e. a thread can hand off execution to another thread while it is I/O-blocked.